# Changing ListView's ItemPanelTemplate Orientation

Tags: listview, uwp, datatemplate, uwp-xaml

I have a `ListView` in a `DataTemplate` in my app page. I want to use it in two different places, 1. on top and then secondly on the side.
Now I have an `ItemPanelTemplate` in it so I can easily manage it how to display the View but I cant seem to change the `Orientation` in `VisualStateManager`. It simply doesn't work. It works if I change the `Orientation` directly in the `StackPanel` but it doesn't work like that.
The code I am trying is:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Name="SidePaneTemplate">
        <UserControl>
            <ListView SelectionChanged="TopListBox_SelectionChanged"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="TemplatePanel"
                                    >
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="w_state">
                                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="550"
                                                             MinWindowWidth="451"/>
                                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="TemplatePanel.Orientation"
                                                    Value="Vertical"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="n_state">
                                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="TemplatePanel.Orientation"
                                                    Value="Horizontal"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.Items>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE8B2;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Movies"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE7F4;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="TV Shows"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE721;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Search"
                                   TextAlignment="DetectFromContent"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE728;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Favorites"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE713;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Settings"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

If someone has any idea how can I do this please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

**Update:**
I tried both the answers below but unfortunately it's the same thing as it was before. Once the panel gets set at the start time whether it's `Horizontal` or `Vertical` it stays the same for me. It doesn't change the `Orientation` for some reason.

Here is the code for the whole page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--
    <DataTemplate x:Name="SidePaneTemplate">
        <UserControl>
            <UserControl.Resources>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="SidePanelTemp">
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="TopPanelTemp">
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </UserControl.Resources>
            <ListView SelectionChanged="TopListBox_SelectionChanged"
                      Name="List"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="550"
                                                 MinWindowWidth="451"/>
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="List.ItemsPanel"
                                        Value="{StaticResource SidePanelTemp}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"
                                                 />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="List.ItemsPanel"
                                        Value="{StaticResource TopPanelTemp}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <ListView.Items>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE8B2;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Movies"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE7F4;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="TV Shows"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE721;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Search"
                                   TextAlignment="DetectFromContent"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE728;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Favorites"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE713;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Settings"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DoubleSidePaneTemplate">
        <UserControl>
            <UserControl.Resources>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel">
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VerticalStackPanel">
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </UserControl.Resources>
            <ListView
                x:Name="rootview"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectionChanged="TopListBox_SelectionChanged"
                SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListView.Items>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon
                                Margin="5"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                Glyph="&#xE8B2;"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Movies" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon
                                Margin="5"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                Glyph="&#xE7F4;"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="TV Shows" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon
                                Margin="5"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                Glyph="&#xE721;" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Search" TextAlignment="DetectFromContent" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon
                                Margin="5"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                Glyph="&#xE728;" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Favorites"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon
                                Margin="5"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                Glyph="&#xE713;" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Settings" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView.Items>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="w_state">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger  MinWindowWidth="500" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="rootview.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource VerticalStackPanel }" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="n_state">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="rootview.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource  HorizontalStackPanel}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </ListView>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--    
    <DataTemplate x:Name="TopPaneTemplate">
        <UserControl>
            <ListView SelectionChanged="TopListBox_SelectionChanged"
                      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource TopPanelTemp}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <ListView.Items>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE8B2;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Movies"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE7F4;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="TV Shows"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE721;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Search"
                                   TextAlignment="DetectFromContent"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE728;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Favorites"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                  Glyph="&#xE713;"
                                  Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Settings"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
-->
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="550"
                                     MinWindowHeight="451"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyUITheme.Edge"
                            Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Target="IndexPane.IsPaneOpen"
                        Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="TopPane.Visibility"
                            Value="Collapsed"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyUITheme.Edge"
                            Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Target="IndexPane.IsPaneOpen"
                        Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Target="TopPane.Visibility"
                            Value="Visible"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EdgeUIThemeTransition x:Name="MyUITheme"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.Transitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Viewbox x:Name="TopPane"
             MaxHeight="50">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DoubleSidePaneTemplate}"/>
    </Viewbox>

    <SplitView Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               x:Name="IndexPane"
               OpenPaneLength="100"
               DisplayMode="Inline"
               PaneBackground="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DoubleSidePaneTemplate}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Frame x:Name="PaneContentFrame"/>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            x:Name="InternetPanel"
                            Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
                            MaxWidth="500">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsInternet, Mode=OneWay}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                               Margin="10">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="LocalNotifStoryboard"
                                Completed="LocalNotifStoryboard_Completed">
                        <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="True"
                                         FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                         Duration="0:0:3"
                                         From="0"
                                         To="1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="InternetPanel"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(InternetPanel.Opacity)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Grid.Resources>
            </Grid>

        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

I am using `ContentPresenter` to show the `Templates`, can this be the reason for this not changing the `Orientation`? Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Did you set Both to `Horizontal`?

Comment: No that's a mistake. I was just checking if something works but I'll correct it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @James Croft said that you could not place `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` under the `<ItemsPanelTemplate>`.
And you could create some resources for `<VisualState.Setters>` and then move the visual states to the `UserControl` level.

> I cannot create two different DataTemplates for this. Otherwise it would be the same thing that I am already doing. I want to be able to use one template for two different places and change the template properties during runtime.

For your scenario you just need to move `resources` from  `<Page.Resources>` to  `<UserControl.Resources>` base on James Croft's answer. And you can reference the follow code sample.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SidePaneTemplate">
            <UserControl>
                <UserControl.Resources>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel">
                        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VerticalStackPanel">
                        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </UserControl.Resources>
                <ListView
                    x:Name="rootview"
                    Margin="0,10,0,0"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListView.Items>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE8B2;"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Movies" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE7F4;"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="TV Shows" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE721;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Search" TextAlignment="DetectFromContent" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE728;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Favorites"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE713;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Settings" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </ListView.Items>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="w_state">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger  MinWindowWidth="0" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="rootview.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource VerticalStackPanel }" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="n_state">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="700" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="rootview.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource  HorizontalStackPanel}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ListView>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And this is `Datatemplate` effect.
[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I even tried your own code but it didn't work. So please take a look at my whole page and let me know if I am doing something wrong. I updated my question.

Comment: The code above in my answer is complete `Datatemlpate`. You could use it directly. Just lke the following code  `<Viewbox x:Name="TopPane"
             MaxHeight="50">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SidePaneTemplate}"/>
        </Viewbox>`.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. I just renamed it to "DoubleSidePaneTemplate" and put it there but it's still the same.

Comment: You could reference the [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ItemPanelTemplateOrientationTest.git) project that uploaded to github.

Comment: My project is not uploaded to GitHub.

Comment: Yes your sample works but I have no idea as to why my code doesn't work because they are really identical to each other, except names. And still my code doesn't show the expected output but your does. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you checked the value of  `AdaptiveTrigger` ?

Comment: Yes I did, in my code it didn't work but in your code all of it worked. So I have edited your code to suit my needs and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do this at the level you're attempting to do it at.

You will need to create ItemsPanelTemplate resources for the orientations you're supporting and then move the visual states to the Grid which contains the ListView. The reason for wrapping the ListView in a Grid is that the visual states will not always guarantee firing if they are at the root UserControl level.

Here's an example of how you would do this:

```
     <DataTemplate x:Name="SidePaneTemplate">
        <UserControl>
            <UserControl.Resources>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VerticalStackPanel">
                    <StackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </UserControl.Resources>

            <Grid>
                <ListView
                    x:Name="List"
                    Margin="0,10,0,0"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectionChanged="TopListBox_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="TemplatePanel">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="w_state">
                                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="550" MinWindowWidth="451" />
                                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Target="TemplatePanel.Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="n_state">
                                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Target="TemplatePanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.Items>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE8B2;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Movies" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE7F4;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="TV Shows" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE721;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Search" TextAlignment="DetectFromContent" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE728;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Favorites" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FontIcon
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                    Glyph="&#xE713;" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Settings" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </ListView.Items>
                </ListView>

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="w_state">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="550" MinWindowWidth="451" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="List.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource VerticalStackPanel}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="n_state">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="List.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalStackPanel}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: It worked for a couple of times but not anymore. So I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I cannot create two different `DataTemplates` for this. Otherwise it would be the same thing that I am already doing. I want to be able to use one template for two different places and change the template properties during runtime.

Comment: @Ahmar you wouldn't be creating two DataTemplates. The layout here will map to your UserControl as it currently is. My example is probably not the best because it shows the usage in a page. I will update

Comment: @Ahmar I've updated the answer with the XAML which you should just be able to lift and shift into your own application using the scenario that you've provided in the question.